# MultiValueDictKeyError: 'category'

Tags: django, ajax, post

hi guys i am trying to insert information into my database using django and ajax i am quite new to this if i click submit without using ajax the form will submit as expected but if i try using ajax then i get internal server error 500 which make me confused**your text**

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def post_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        order_id = request.POST['order_id']
        category = request.POST['category']
        product = request.POST['product']
        price_per_unit = request.POST['price_per_unit']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        price_all = request.POST['price_all']

        new_order = PoductOrder(order_id=order_id, Category=Category.objects.get(name=category), 
        product=Product.objects.get(name=product), price_per_unit=price_per_unit, qantity=quantity, price_all=price_all )
        new_order.save()
        return HttpResponse('data has being saved')
```

POST.JS

```
$(document).on('submit', '#post_form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"/order/postorder",
        data:{
            order_id:$('#order_cart').val(),
            category:$('category').val(),
            product:$('#product').val(),
            price_per_unit:$('#per_unit').val(),
            quantity:$('#quantity').val(),
            price_all:$('#total').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),

        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
           console.log(error)
        }
    });
});
```

MYFORM

```
 <div class="row">

            <form action="{% url 'post-order' %}" method="post" id="post_form">
                 {% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="order_id">Order ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name='order_id' class= 'form-control' id='order_cart' >

                </div>              
              </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="status">Product Category</label>
                    <select required name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">--Select Product Category--</option>
                        {% for category in category %}
                    
                        <option value="{{ category.name }}">{{category.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                            </select>     
                                   </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="customer">Product</label>
`                   <select required name="product" id="product" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">--Select Product--</option>  
                    {% for products in products %}
                    
                    <option value="{{ products.name }}">{{ products.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ERROR TRACEBAK
Internal Server Error: /order/postorder
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 84, in **getitem**
list_ = super().**getitem**(key)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'category'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
response = get_response(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\INVENTORY MANAGEMENT\dashboard\views.py", line 50,
in post_order
category = request.POST['category']
~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 86, in **getitem**
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'category'
[27/Apr/2023 11:44:48] "POST /order/postorder HTTP/1.1" 500 74249

Comment: The JS is sending multiple data for the category. You might want to check why it is sending all the options rather than the selected one.

Comment: please how can i check for that

Comment: thanks so much i actually omit '#' in category:$('#category').val(),

Answer (score 0):

In django .get() query used for getting one object from database. generally it is used with id but you are using with name if your query return more than one object in .get() query then django will throw MultiValueDictKeyError.

Comment: okay thanks this was also useful